# Qt: Take over system open file dialog

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, qwebview, qfiledialog

I would like to automate the upload of a file to a website using PyQt4's QWebView, but there's a part I can't figure out yet. To upload the file, the website has a button, which opens a dialog from which you are supposed to select the local file. So, these are my questions :) Is there a way to control that dialog once I click the button? Is there a better way to achieve this?

*edit*

The website is https://maps.google.com/ and I'm uploading a .kml file through *My Places > Create Map > Import*.

Comment: Could you provide the website url?

Comment: @enginefree sure, will edit the post

Comment: Did the answer I provided work?

Comment: @enginefree couldn't check it out yet, but it looks good, i'll probably adjudicate you the bounty before the time limit expires, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible what you're looking for is [QWebPage::chooseFile](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwebpage.html#chooseFile)() (I suppose it depends also on how the website is handling that). Reimplement that and see if it is sufficient. Do whatever you want and return the chosen file path.

EDIT: Now that you provided the link I tested and seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, to begin let me start with background information and references.

The module that I will be using is `pywin32` download [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/?source=navbar), specifically the `win32gui`, API reference [here](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32gui.html).

Now before you can manipulate the dialog you have to "navigate" to the window handle, the following uses `win32.FindWindow` API Reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499.aspx), which looks like this, where the two inputs are the `lpclassName` in this case `#32770` (stands for a dialog) reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the `lpWindowName` which in this case is `File Upload`,

```
HWND WINAPI FindWindow(
  _In_opt_  LPCTSTR lpClassName,
  _In_opt_  LPCTSTR lpWindowName
);
```

Code to locate file handle:

```
import win32gui

control = win32gui.FindWindow("#32770", "File Upload")
```

And it stores the handle, which in my case was `721470`.

The next step is locate the handles of the GUI objects in the dialog, i will show an example of the `Cancel` button. To find the handle, I wil be using `FindWindowEx` API reference here,

```
import win32con
import win32api

ButtonHandle = win32gui.FindWindowEx(control, 0, "Button", "Cancel");
win32api.SendMessage(ButtonHandle, win32con.BM_CLICK, 0, 0)
```

Reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the `BM_CLICK` and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the `SendMessage`.

Final code:

```
import win32gui
import win32api
import win32con

window = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
title = win32gui.GetWindowText(window)
control = win32gui.FindWindow("#32770", "File Upload")
ButtonHandle = win32gui.FindWindowEx(control, 0, "Button", "Cancel")
win32api.SendMessage(ButtonHandle, win32con.BM_CLICK, 0, 0)
```

Another way is to use the `watsup.winGuiAuto` module, [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/watsup/), example below:

```
from watsup.winGuiAuto import *

optDialog = findTopWindow(wantedText="File Upload")

CancelButton = findControl(optDialog,wantedClass="Button", wantedText="Cancel")

clickButton(SaveButton)
```

But i believe the easiest way is to use `autoit` [here](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/), i have used it before in pyqt, to shoot out commands.

Hope this helps!

Additional References (pywin32 versions):

`win32gui` [here](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32gui.html)

`win32api` [here](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32api.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure PyQt4 demo that more or less reproduces the default implementation:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit

class WebPage(QtWebKit.QWebPage):
    def chooseFile(self, frame=None, path=''):
        return QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self.parent(), '', path)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QtWebKit.QWebView()
    view.setPage(WebPage(view))
    view.load(QtCore.QUrl('https://maps.google.com/'))
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```